# Interrupt a running thread to execute an action triggered by a JButton click

Tags: java, actionlistener

we are still working with the nasty robots and got another problem (after solving our package problem).
We have a robot which is running in a thread. He runs constantly forwards (move() method) and is checking if the currentDir variable has changed. If it has changed, he would call another method to get face the new direction.

Our problem is that we have to change the currentDir variable somehow. We want to do this by calling the setDir() method of our robot which is running in the thread.
This function is called after an event happened, triggered by a JButton.
But we can not manage to interrupt the thread to call this method.

Is it maybe possible to create a listener listening in the thread itself for a ActionEvent triggered by a JButton?

```
   public void run()
    {
          //Infinite while-loop to check for the Direction of the robot
          while(true)
          {
                 if(currentDir != getDirection()) // if currentdir is not
                 {
                       if(currentDir == Direction.NORTH)
                            goNorth();
                       else if(currentDir == Direction.EAST)
                            goEast();
                       else if(currentDir == Direction.SOUTH)
                            goSouth();

                       else
                            goWest();
                  }
                  else
                       move();
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to set the direction from the same thread. If you set it from the UI thread in the listener, the thread should be able to just pick it up.

You might want to also make the direction variable `volatile`. http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_typical_use.shtml